# Unsure about the best way to fully separate my Dojo layers

Tags: dojo-build, dojo, dojo-1.7

Hey so I'm finding the documentation around building dojo a little hazy around layers.

For my **Dojo 1.7+** application I would like a layer that contains only Dojo, and a layer that only contains my code, so I can place the appropriate copyright/license headers at the top.

Looking at build profile template, I see:

```javascript
layers : {
    "dojo/dojo":{
        include:["dojo/dojo","dojo/i18n","dojo/ready","dojo/domReady"]
    },
    "myapp/core":{
        include:["myapp/core/module1","myapp/core/module2","myapp/core/module3"],
        exclude:["dojo/dojo"]
    }
}
```

But when I look inside my `'myapp/core'` layer js file I see lots of occurrences of

```
'define("dojo*'.
```

I started tackling this by finding each occurrence of the dojo define and putting that in the dojo/dojo layer include list, but that doesn't seem like the appropriate way of doing layers, is it? At the very least can't I just include certain packages? Am I making a big misunderstanding here?

**Bonus** it seems like the layer property 'copyrightFile' no longer works. Has that been deprecated, or changed?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Are all these (`"dojo/i18n","dojo/ready","dojo/domReady"`) dependencies the only dependencies that your external modules need?  If `myapp/core/module2` requires a dojo module that is not included in the dojo core layer, then it will be included in the `myapp/core` layer.

I have gone down the path you are going found it difficult to maintain the separation of code over time.  I would create a single layer with both dojo and your code.

Use a layer to encapsulate code that is for specific area of functionality.  For example, I have a graphical workflow editor that has it's own layer because it includes a bunch of svg code that doesn't need to be present in the rest of the application.

Comment: Thanks, I think I have no choice but to build a layer by function rather than by 'package'. My external modules use a lot of Dojo/dijit/dojox modules (quite a big list actually) and I was hoping to just have a layer of dojo and a layer of my stuff.